# Encoding issues when POSTing to REST using HttpUtility.ParseQueryString

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, rest, post

I'm having an issue with encoding to a proper x-www-form-urlencoded format when POSTing a message to a RESTful web service that contains national characters.

To build a query string, I was thinking of using [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150047(v=vs.110).aspx) method with UTF8 encoding and calling `ToString` on that.

I need a key value pair `name=Nicolò Piccolo'` to be formatted as `Niccol%C3%B2%20Piccolo%27`. What I'm getting from the method instead is `name=Nicol%u00f2+Piccolo%27`.

Note that the `%27` at the end is correct, so how can I make the utility use `%27` instead of `+` and so on?

It is causing HTTP 404 status to be returned by the server.

See the example here on .net fiddle with different encodings: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vDfp1c

**Edit**

Now when I add a key using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`, it ends up having an extra `%25` prefix for each encoded character: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HIugDo: `name=Nicol%25c3%25b2%2bPiccolo%2527`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With still no replies, just to keep the StackOverflow website clean, I'll post an answer here.

I've ended up with reconstructing the QueryString manually by iterating over the collection and URL encoding the keys and values, and not calling ToString().